# .Net 7 MAUI Buttons IsVisible=true don't display them after upd. Image element many times on Android

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, maui, .net-7.0

I have a `ContentPage` with a few `Button`-s and `Image` element. I hide some buttons, display about 50 different images by updating the bound `byte[]` prop in a ViewModel, and set each hidden button `IsVisible` back to `true`, but the buttons don't re-appear. If I press the Android `Home` button and immediately come back to the app where I left, I see the buttons I was trying to display all where they should be.

What this functionality is for.
We are working with a peripheral device that sends us a sequence of images represented by `byte[]`s each. We display them in the app. At some point, the device stops sending this images, we get the notification about that and display buttons to a user to proceed with the next steps. As it is shown above, the buttons don't appear.

Additional info:

1. If I don't update the image, or update it just a few times, the buttons hiding/showing works as it should.
2. The images are ~400x400 px and we need to show them with frame rate about 7-15 per second.
3. If there is a better way to show such a sequence of images we could go for. The only alternative I see now is to convert them into a video feed on the fly and display it with an appropriate MAUI control. But that seems to be an overkill. So I would prefer just to find a way working with displaying the images one by one.

**UPD1:** When I decrease the image frequency update to 0.7 frames/sec - this error disappears from logs: `Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` and the app works as expected. This is the case when I'm getting the image asynchronously from device and have VM updates in `Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(..)`.

##### How to reproduce:

###### Prerequisites:

- Page (`.xaml`-based) bound to the ViewModel

  - A few buttons (`Ok`, `Cancel`, `Repeat`, `Selector`)
  - `Image`
- `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` `[ObservableObject]`-based ViewModel
- An array of 10 slightly different images, approximately 400x400 px, represented by their `byte[]` values
- Build for android. I tried with 21 and 33, no difference.

###### Steps:

1. Show/Hide buttons in a different order a few times by updating the properties of the `ViewModel` with the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute, bound to the `IsVisible` property of the corresponding buttons.
2. Hide all the buttons except `Cancel`.
3. Display all the images in the `Image` element consecutively one after another, 50 times with a delay of 100 ms (50 Image.Source updates in total within ~5 seconds).
4. Set the properties bound to `IsVisible` of the buttons to `true`.

###### Expected Result:

- All the buttons are displayed.

###### Actual Result:

- Only `Cancel` is visible; other buttons are not, even though `HorizontalStackLayout.HorizontalOptions` is set to `Center`, and the `Cancel` button is shifted to the side as if the other buttons occupy space on the layout but are not visible. If a user switches to another app and immediately back, or opens and closes another window, all the buttons become visible after that.

##### Code

I've isolated this issue into a separate app which is available there: https://gitlab.com/e-shevchuk/imagebuttonissuerepro. But they key snippets you can see right here below:

`CapturePage.xaml` - the page where I reproduce the issue

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="App.CapturePage"
             Title="CapturePage">

    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="False" IsVisible="False"/>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter  x:Key="ByteArrayToImg" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 0" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <VerticalStackLayout ClassId="CaptureSection"
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Spacing="5" 
                Padding="0,10,0,10" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                IsVisible="{Binding CaptureSectionVisible}">

                <Image 
                    Source="{Binding ImageBytes, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImg}}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding ImageVisible}"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                <Label 
                    Text="{Binding LabelText}" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            </VerticalStackLayout>

            <HorizontalStackLayout ClassId="Button section"
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                VerticalOptions="Start">

                <Button
                    x:Name="FingerSelectorBtn"
                    IsVisible="{Binding FingerSelectorButtonVisible}"
                    Text="Finger Selector"/>
                <Button
                    x:Name="CaptureNextBtn"
                    IsVisible="{Binding CaptureNextButtonVisible}"
                    Text="Next"/>
                <Button
                    x:Name="RepeatBtn"
                    IsVisible="{Binding RepeatButtonVisible}"
                    Text="Repeat"/>
                <Button
                    x:Name="CloseBtn"
                    IsVisible="{Binding CloseButtonVisible}"
                    Text="Close" 
                    Clicked="OnCloseBtnClicked"/>

            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

`CapturePage.xaml.cs` with code behind and ViewModel:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace App;

public partial class CapturePage : ContentPage
{
    public CaptureViewModel ViewModel => (CaptureViewModel)BindingContext;
    public CapturePage(CaptureViewModel vm)
    {
        ThreadUtil.LogCurrentThead("CapturePage.CapturePage():");

        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
        Task.Run(DisplayImages);
    }

    public void OnCloseBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }

    private async Task DisplayImages()
    {
        ThreadUtil.LogCurrentThead("CapturePage.DisplayImages():");
        (byte[] bytes, string fileName)? image = null;

        // Initialize the PeripheralDevice
        var device = new PeripheralDevice();

        // Hide buttons all the buttons, except [ Close ]

        await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            ThreadUtil.LogCurrentThead("CapturePage.DisplayImages(): Update VM props");
            ViewModel.FingerSelectorButtonVisible = false;
            ViewModel.CaptureNextButtonVisible = false;
            ViewModel.RepeatButtonVisible = false;
            ViewModel.CloseButtonVisible = true;
        });

        // Display all the images one by one in the Image element

        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            device.Reset();

            do
            {

                image = await device.GetNextImageAsync();
                if (image is null) break;

                await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
                {
                    ThreadUtil.EnsureUIThread();
                    ViewModel.ImageBytes = image?.bytes;
                    ViewModel.LabelText = $"Image {image?.fileName}";
                });
            }
            while (image is not null);
        }

        // Display all the buttons

        await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            ThreadUtil.LogCurrentThead("CapturePage.DisplayImages(): Update VM props");
            ViewModel.FingerSelectorButtonVisible = true;
            ViewModel.CaptureNextButtonVisible = true;
            ViewModel.RepeatButtonVisible = true;
        });
    }
}

public partial class CaptureViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // Images

    [ObservableProperty]
    public byte[] imageBytes;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool imageVisible = true;

    // Section
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool captureSectionVisible = true;

    // Buttons

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool fingerSelectorButtonVisible;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool captureNextButtonVisible;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool repeatButtonVisible;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool closeButtonVisible;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string labelText;
}

public class PeripheralDevice
{
    private readonly List<string> _imageFileNames;
    private readonly List<byte[]> _imagesBytes;
    private readonly TimeSpan _delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);

    private int idx = 0;

    public PeripheralDevice()
    {

        // Get images bytes

        var imagePrefix = "dummy-preview-";
        _imageFileNames = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            _imageFileNames.Add($"{imagePrefix}{i:D2}.jpeg");

        var imageFilePaths = _imageFileNames
            .Select(Helpers.InitAndOrGetPath)
            .ToList();

        _imagesBytes = imageFilePaths
            .Select(File.ReadAllBytes)
            .ToList();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits asynchronously and return the image 10 times and file name
    /// <summary/>
    public async Task<(byte[] bytes, string fileName)?> GetNextImageAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(_delay));
        var i = idx++;

        if (i < _imagesBytes.Count)
            return (_imagesBytes[i], _imageFileNames[i]);

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the device returned image counter
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset()
    {
        idx = 0;
    }
}
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs` - has one purpose to display the page with an image and buttons. Show it here just in case:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnOpenTheWindowBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenCapturePage(this);
    }

    public async void OpenCapturePage(Page parentPage)
    {
        var viewModel = new CaptureViewModel();
        var page = new CapturePage(viewModel);

        await parentPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    }
}
```

The project .csproj:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>App</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>App</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.app</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>7c1f1777-b956-44ca-a483-9d883247d775</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="5.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="CapturePage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Thank you for your help, in advance! ;)

Comment: if you want to show a series of images in sequence, use a Timer and update the image each time the timer fires.  I'm also not sure why you're reading the `byte[]` for each image instead of just binding to the path.

Comment: Hi @jason, thank you for the reply. **1.** The images are supplied by the peripheral device. I don't have control over how frequently they come. So I don't see what role a timer can play there. What am I missing? **2.** I get them as `byte[]`-s. In the sample code they are pulled from the Resource to to `byte[]` to make an issue reproducible, since you don't have a usb device that generates a sequence of `byte[]`-s representing images.

Comment: your current code is a for loop and a Thread.Sleep - how does that work with images coming from a peripheral device?  How is your app notified when a new image appears, or when the sequence is complete?

Comment: @jason, I'm calling `await device.GetNextImage()` in a loop, that awaits till a new image arrive and returns the new `byte[] image` value, that I display same as in a sample. I've tried to circumvent this issue in may ways, including, adding a device call for each new image and updating the `ViewModel.Image` prop from that event from the same thread, Main thread or UI thread. The result is still the same.

Comment: that is not shown in the code you posted.  Fundamentally you're blocking the UI thread.  I don't think using `Task.Run` in the constructor does what you think - quite a lot has been written about how to best call async methods from the constructor

Comment: @Jason, thank you for the hypothesis, I'm afraid it is not the case. I really wish that was the case. I have these `ThreadUtil.LogCurrentThead("CapturePage.CapturePage():");` statements in the constructor and method displaying image and buttons. They show execution on different threads, and `DisplayImages()` is not on UI one. Moreover buttons visibility changes to `true` in a synch way at the end of the method after the `Sleep(1000)`, so even if that method was blocking the thread, it would release it immediately after the props upd, allowing CommunityToolkit.Mvvm do its "magic", updading UI.

Comment: @Jason, also, I've written above, that I tried updating the image from callbacks generated by the device SDK directly, that was also from non UI threads and issues didn't go anywhere : (

Comment: 1) If put breakpoint on code after "// Display all the buttons", is the breakpoint reached? 2) The button display code looks correct. Lets help Maui by getting back to UI thread. This ensures any previous UI operation has completed: `Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => { ...the three lines that make buttons visible... });`

Comment: Wow, @ToolmakerSteve, you wouldn't believe. This is exactly what I've done, before reading your comment, and moved image extraction in cycle into async method too. When the refresh rate is less than 0.8 frames/sec - it all works like a charm. If I set 0.2 sec int `private readonly TimeSpan _delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)`, in 100% cases I get the issue behavior. I updated the code above and in the repo.

Comment: Those Dispatcher methods should have fixed it. The timing-dependent error ("Only the original thread ...") suggests some code not running on UI thread - but I don't see any issue in your code. Besides, if it was your code, it should happen at any speed. I recommend creating a new `github maui issue`. But this code is a bit complicated. See if you can reduce it to the minimum code that gives that "original thread" message, but only does so when display quickly. For example, can you get it to happen using that toolkit converter, showing the same byte array over and over quickly?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, Yep, I've posted the issue to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16718. I'm almost finished now, but will follow your advice and try to simplify the "reproducing app" even more tomorrow. Thank you! P.S.: Yes. That is my code ; ), but the speed changes behavior unfortunately. So I think, this is bug after all. Let's what MAUI guys at GitHub answer within next few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with [MmImageLoading](https://github.com/Level28-de/MmImageLoading) instead of standard MAUI `Image` component. Works with 100 images per second. Here are the needed changes (you can see the full version in my repo [currently most recent commit](https://gitlab.com/e-shevchuk/imagebuttonissuerepro/-/commit/a8c59d951e46262af9355ea99c93864bffb55a80?action=show&controller=projects%2Fcommit&id=a8c59d951e46262af9355ea99c93864bffb55a80&namespace_id=e-shevchuk&project_id=imagebuttonissuerepro&w=1)):

**Minimal changes:**

`.csproj` only add the package

```xml
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="MmImageLoading" Version="0.7.6" />
    ...
```

`MainProgram.cs`

```cs
    ...
    .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()

    #if (ANDROID || IOS)
    .UseMmImageLoading()
    #endif

    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    ...
```

`CapturePage.xaml` - add to `<ContentPage>`:

```xml
    xmlns:maui="clr-namespace:MmImageLoading.MAUI;assembly=de.level28.MmImageLoading.NuGet"
```

+ use `<maui:CachedImage .. />` instead of `Image` component.

The rest of the code is the same.

**Additional comments**

- Gerald Versluis from MS tells that they may even will support this component in future [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDtx5ORYrmw&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis).
- I will still follow up [this issue with MAUI team on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16718), hopefully they fix the `Image` component one day too.

**The last, but not least**, @ToolmakerSteve and all the others, thank you for your participation and helping solving this issue.